# excel combo box populate

Tags: excel, vba

In my excel sheet1 i have 2 combo box...

1. When i open the excel the 2 combox has to fill
2. if i select one value in one combo box the corressponding should populate in the second combo box

Answer (score 0):

if they're populating from the same source data, it's easy - you can insert them as "Forms" ComboBoxes (not ActiveX ones) and on the properties set the "cell link" value to be the same cell. That way when the selected index of one changes, the other will change too.

If they're populating from different lists, it's a bit harder. You'll have to determine that one is the master and then inside the "Cell Link" cell for the "slave" ComboBox, you'll have to do a MATCH() into the lookup data for the second with an INDEX() into the lookup table for the first to determine what its value is. Will provide a bit more info if required.